# I am finding the next line after matching a line using startswith in python but i have multiple spaces between lines

Tags: python

```
Escape character is '^]'.


abc-2#terminal length 0
```

I am reading multiple files and This is the content i have in files and I am trying find the next line using "Escape character is '^]'." and Every file has different number of spaces in between 2 lines.

I am writing below code, but it is printing empty

```
with open(report_file_path, "r") as in_file:
     for line in in_file:
         abc="Escape character is '^]'."
         if line.strip() == abc:
             result= next(in_file)
             print result

             #Output should be : abc-2#terminal length 0
```

but I am getting empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while loop` to check if the next line have any content.

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename2, "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        abc="Escape character is '^]'."
        if line.strip()==abc:
            while True:
                result= next(in_file)
                if result.strip():
                    break
            print(result)
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, In previous result "abc-2#terminal length 0" , I want split using special character (Special character can vary everytime).